# oAuth2 - WSO2 API Manager and Identity Server Integration

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, authorization, wso2, token

I would like to implement an architecture based on oAuth2 in which the token is generated by the WSO2 identity server (Auth Server) and the API manager is used as the Gateway (resource server).

I understood it's necessary to change the `Identity_Server/repository/conf/carbon.xml` and set the value false for the element `<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>` in order to enable the admin Service of token validation exposed by the Identity Server. Also I think it's necessary to configure the APIManager.xml to configure the API manager to check the token validation using a service exposed by the identity server.

But unfortunately the specific documentation is not available at [https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM140/Configuring+api-manager.xm](https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM140/Configuring+api-manager.xml). Can someone help me understand how to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's correct to assume what you want is to, secure a exposed rest API with OAuth, using WSO2 IS, then the following link [1] will help you.

But since you are using WSO2 API manager, if there is no other restriction you can simply achieve this token generation functionality from API-manager itself. There is an OathTokenEndPoint exposed by API-M. You can call this endpoint with client-key and secret to get a token.[2]

[1] - http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2014/02/securing-your-web-service-with-oauth2.html

[2] - https://docs.wso2.org/display/IS410/OAuth+2.0+Grant+Types+with+WSO2+API+Manager+Authorization+Code

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support. I've created a custom handler to let the AM validate the token calling the IS. The token has been correctly validated but then I encountered the following exception:ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/security/APISecurityUtils
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler.doRoleBasedAccessThrottling(APIThrottleHandler.java:416), any suggestions about this ?